# Can't query with mongodb-1.1.x php driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I just updated mongodb to version 3.2 and updated my php driver to the [latest](http://php.net/manual/tr/set.mongodb.php). Here is the [docs](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library).

They changed almost everything with this new driver and there is not enough documentation I think. I couldn't find how to count, limit and sort the data with php as before.

I found [sort method](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) in mongodb website, but there is nothing about it in php docs and source code.

Is there anyone who has dealt with this new driver? How can I sort and limit my query results with php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the new mongo php driver, unlike the old version which just requires mongo.so or mongo.dll to be installed, you will need to get the package mongodb/mongodb through composer:

```
composer.phar require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0@beta"
```

Then you can use this example for an initial try:

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // include Composer goodies

    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    $collection = new MongoDB\Collection($manager, "db_name.collection_name");

    $result = $collection->find( [ 'id' => '1', 'name' => 'John' ] );

    foreach ($result as $entry)
    {
        echo $entry->id, ': ', $entry->name, "\n";
    }
?>
```

More examples can be found in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/examples/bulkwrite.php and https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/examples/write.php

The count method can be found in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Collection.php

sort and limit are the options to add to find() method:

```
$options = [
    'sort' => ['id' => 1],
    'limit' => 5
];
 $result = $collection->find( [ 'id' => '1', 'name' => 'John' ], $options );
```